# Set static fields on custom View from XML

Tags: android, xml, static-members, declare-styleable

This is a custom view

```
public class MyView extends Button {
    private static int color;

    . . . 
}
```

This XML instantiates MyView several times

```
<LinearLayout . . .>

    <com.example.test.MyView . . . />
    <com.example.test.MyView . . . />
    <com.example.test.MyView . . . />
    <com.example.test.MyView . . . />
    <com.example.test.MyView . . . />
    <com.example.test.MyView . . . />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to know what is the proper way to initialize the static `color` from XML.
I know already one solution (but I wonder if there is a different recommended way):

- Define a custom attribute

> ```
> <declare-stylable name=MyView>
>     <attr name="color" format="integer" />
> </declare-stylable>
> ```

- Use the custom attribute on the instantiation of any `MyView`

> ```
> <com.example.test.MyView
>     app:color="@color/red"
>     . . ./>
> ```

- Set the static field during MyView constructor

> TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyView, defStyle, 0);
>      int c = a.getInteger(R.styleable.MyView_color, -1);
>      if( c != -1 ) color = c;

The only thing that I don't like about this solution is that it is dependent on a `MyView` instantiation, usually, in code, static fields and methods can be accessed independently, so I would like to know if there is a way I can set the static field also independently of the `MyView` actual instantitations.

Comment: I know of no way to set a static variable in a custom view (or any view for that matter) using XML. I would be surprised if there is.